# Stored property type 'CGPoint' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable',

Tags: swift, swiftui, hashable

Imagine a card board. All cards are on a view I call CardBoard.

All cards are on an array:

```
var cards:[Card]
```

Every card has its own position.

This is Card

```
struct Card: View {
  let id = UUID()
  
  var name:String
  var code:String
  var filename:String
  var position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 250)
  
  
  init(name:String, code:String, filename:String) {
    self.name = name
    self.code = code
    self.filename = filename
  }
  
  
  var body: some View {
    Image(filename)
      .position(position)
  }
}
```

Now I want to draw them on the screen.

```
var body: some View {
  ZStack {
    ForEach(cards, id:\.self) {card in
       
    }
  }
}
```

when I try this, Xcode tells me

```
Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'Card' conform to 'Hashable'
```

when I add `Hashable` to `Card`

```
struct Card: View, Hashable {

1. Stored property type 'CGPoint' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable', preventing synthesized conformance of 'Card' to 'Hashable'
```

any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to add an extension to `CGPoint` to make it hashable.

Comment: @Alexander Or just implement `Hashable` on `Card` explicitly.

Comment: Conform ```func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    }```

Comment: @Sulthan: That may be the better solution. As I understand it from https://forums.swift.org/t/retroactive-conformances-vs-swift-in-the-os/14393, adding conformance of standard library types to standard library protocols retroactively has some subtle issues.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

THANKS EVERYBODY, but because is not good to post a link as a solution, I am posting here:

The solution is to make the view Hashable and add this:

```
extension CGPoint : Hashable {
  public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(x)
    hasher.combine(y)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a bunch of types that need the same treatment (which are often named 2-tuples). e.g.

```swift
extension CGPoint: HashableSynthesizable { }
extension CLLocationCoordinate2D: HashableSynthesizable { }
extension MKCoordinateRegion: HashableSynthesizable { }
extension MKCoordinateSpan: HashableSynthesizable { }
```

```swift
/// A type whose `Hashable` conformance could be auto-synthesized,
/// but either the API provider forgot, or more likely,
/// the API is written in Objective-C, and hasn't been modernized.
public protocol HashableSynthesizable: Hashable { }

public extension HashableSynthesizable {
  static func == (hashable0: Self, hashable1: Self) -> Bool {
    zip(hashable0.hashables, hashable1.hashables).allSatisfy(==)
  }

  func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hashables.forEach { hasher.combine($0) }
  }
}

private extension HashableSynthesizable {
  var hashables: [AnyHashable] {
    Mirror(reflecting: self).children
      .compactMap { $0.value as? AnyHashable }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your `Card`'s `point` cannot be automatically synthesized because it's a `CGPoint`. Have you tried extending `CGPoint` to conform to `Hashable`?

Here's a really helpful discussion about creating the hashing logic for `CGPoint`: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148763/extending-cgpoint-to-conform-to-hashable

Comment: Note that the accepted answer is very outdated. Use the second answer in the linked question.

Comment: The accepted answer gives an update for post-Swift 4 implementation. Personally I found the discussion interesting when I first ran into this same issue. But yes, good call to point out the second answer.